# After Effects script for replacing footage

Tags: javascript, expression, after-effects

I need to figure out if it is possible to a script (or even a little application) that can open an After Effects project, replace a file (a .mov) a line of text and then render the composition.

I'm aware that this is a simple operation, but this need to be part of a large pipeline and therefor has to be as automatic as possible.

Is this even possible? Could it be done using watch folder? Would I need to create a small application, and if so, what kind of developer am I looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how automatic your process should be.
If AE is already running it should be possible to do this with Javascript/Extendscript.

If you want it fully automatic, you maybe need also some Applescript/Visualbasic to start AE.

After Effects has a startup folder. Where you can place scripts that run when AE launches.
So you could start your process by making your

- system watch that folder.
- If the folder changes start AE.
- Run the startup script. Change the project
- Render.
- End AE. Go back to system watch mode.

---

Answer (score 0):

An AE script can manipulate files on the hard-drive using File and Folder objects:
[File Objects](https://estk.aenhancers.com/3%20-%20File%20System%20Access/file-object.html?highlight=file)

My suggestion would be to build a watchfolder-application in Extendscript. Simply make a script with a never-ending loop, that checks a given folder with an interval. If an AEP file is found, open it, do your thing, save it to a new location and delete the old one.